# javascript & css: найти элемент у которого нет родителя с заданным классом

Tags: javascript, css, css3, классы, queryselectorall

Подскажите как найти элемент у которого нет родителя, даже отдалённого родителя с заданным классом

```
<div class = 'parent1'>
  <div class = 'parent2'>
    <div class = 'element'>Element 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class = 'element'>Element 2</div>
</div>
<div class = 'element'>Element 3</div>
```

если делать

```
document.querySelectorAll(':not(.parent1) .element')
```

то будут найдены все 3 элемента

если делать

```
document.querySelectorAll(':not(.parent1) > .element')
```

то будут найдены 2 элемента

А мне нужно, чтобы находился только элемент который вообще не имеет никакого отношения к элементу с классом `parent1`

P.S.

и подобный вопрос - а можно ли найти только видимый элемент (который не скрыт через `visibility` или `display` сам или через любого из родителей)

Comment: Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.element')).filter(el => !el.closest('.parent1'))

Comment: нашел как невидимость отслеживать (правда только ту, которая `display: none;` - `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.element')).filter(obj => obj.offsetParent)`

Comment: ты можешь попробовать всякие комбинации типа . parent2 > div или .parent1 + div. Подробнее: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators